# confusion about SIR model

Tags: mathematical-modeling

So SIR model is like this:

```
S(n) - S(n-1) = -alpha*S(n-1)I(n-1);
I(n) - I(n-1) = alpha*S(n-1)I(n-1) - beta*I(n-1);
R(n) - R(n-1) = beta*I(n-1);
```

so the susceptible number is decreasing because every time there will be a certain portion of susceptible people get infected. The number of infected people is represented by `alpha*S(n-1)I(n-1)` here. I wonder why it's not just `-alpha*S(n-1)`??? why we have to multiply the I(n-1)??? Please help me understand, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, now I finally understand why it's `alpha*S(n-1)I(n-1)`, because the more infected people, the more people get infected so the number of infected people also matters here. It is called `law of mass action`.